# Profile link not working for Area51 users in chat

Tags: bug, chat, area-51, hyperlinks, broken-link

I recently tried to visit a person's profile from chat room.

I clicked the link to his profile(points to area51) and the link is dead.

[image]

The link points to *discuss.area51.stackexchange.com* and the link should be *area51.meta.stackexchange.com* (as pointed by Shadow Wizard in Tavern on meta).

This link points to an HTTPS error page

[image]

> I am able to reproduce this issue only for users with main profile in area51.

And I think someone missed it in the recent meta url changes from *meta.x.se* to *x.meta.se*

Comment: As far as I know, you can click advanced and proceed anyway, as I believe SE is a safe place :P. Take my word with a grain of salt though.

Comment: @Unitato yes it will work. but it is actually a bug. They missed this in the HTTPS migration